# Adding values in dictionary multiprocessing

Tags: python, multithreading, dictionary, multiprocessing

I need to add values in dictionary using parallelism, in a code below I have used multiprocessing.Process to call function that shoud write value in dictionaty, but it didnt

```
import multiprocessing
import random
manager = multiprocessing.Manager()

users = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 100]

def random_numer_check(user, dict):
        dict[user] = random.randint(0, 1000)


if __name__ == '__main__':

    return_dict = manager.dict()
    jobs = []
    for i in range(10):
        p = multiprocessing.Process(target=random_numer_check, args=(users, return_dict))
        jobs.append(p)
        p.start()

    for proc in jobs:
        proc.join()
```

I expected that result of print(return_dict) will be like

```
{1: 169, 2: 520, 3: 637, 4: 559, 5: 497, 6: 470, 7: 113, 8: 221, 9: 946, 100: 69}
```

But it just returns empty dictionary

Comment: This does not run properly on my system, for two reasons. First, the `manager` needs to be instantiated after the `if __name__ == '__main__:` and second, you need to change the args from `users` to `users[i]`. With those changes it works for me.

Answer (score 2):

You have a few errors in your code it seems. You are trying to pass the whole user list to `random_number_check`. As lists are an unhashable type they cannot be passed to a multiprocessing Process easily.

The code below will work, although I would advise altering your code to follow [the Python style guidelines.](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)

```py
import multiprocessing
import random

users = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 100]
manager = multiprocessing.Manager()


def random_number_check(user, dic):
    dic[user] = random.randint(0, 1000)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    return_dict = manager.dict()

    jobs = []
    for i in range(10):
        # Pass the user at position i instead of the whole list
        p = multiprocessing.Process(target=random_number_check, args=(users[i], return_dict))
        jobs.append(p)
        p.start()

    for proc in jobs:
        proc.join()

    print(return_dict)
```

Comment: Thank you for your anwer, but unfortunately it didnt work for me. It still return empty dictionary

Comment: I just checked and this working on ubuntu, but didn't work through jupyter notebook on windows 10

Comment: I think the code is missing another `if __name__ == '__main__':` for the `manager = multiprocessing.Manager()` line. When adding it, it works fine, otherwise I get a runtime error.